# PHP foreach loop not working on an a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have no idea why this isn't working. I've tried everything. I'm sure I'm missing something.

Here's the array:

```
$userList = array('first_name'=>array('John','Jane'), 'last_name'=>array('Smith','Doe'));
```

The for loop works, I do get a proper output:

```
$usercount = count($userList);  
for($i=0; $i < $usercount; $i++) {  
echo $userList['first_name'][$i];  
}
```

But this foreach loop doesn't:

```
foreach($userList as $user) {  
echo $user['first_name'];  
echo $user['last_name'];  
}
```

What should I do? What's wrong with the code?

Comment: you, probably, want something like this:

array(
    array('first_name' => 'Jone', 'last_name' => 'Smith'),
....
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `first_name` or `last_name` keys in your inner arrays. What `$user` contains is `array('John','Jane')` respectively `array('Smith','Doe')`.

What you probably want though is a structure like:

```
$userList = array(
    array('first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Smith'), 
    array('first_name' => 'Jane', 'last_name' => 'Doe')
);
```

That allows you to use the foreach you allready have.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach approach isn't going to give you the desired output because of the way your array is structured:

```
foreach($userList as $user) {
    //$user is array('John', 'Jane') on the first iteration
}
```

You could update your array to look like this:

```
array(
    array('first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Smith'),
    array('first_name' => 'Jane', 'last_name' => 'Doe')
);
```

Your foreach loop should work with the array structured like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `print_r($userList);` the output is

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Jane
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Smith
            [1] => Doe
        )
)
```

As you can see, you are storing all of the first names in one array and all of the last names in another array.  I think you meant to store each user in their own array.

To do that, you need something like

```
 $userList = array(array("first_name" => "John", "last_name" => "Doe"), array("first_name" => "Jane", "last_name" => "Doe"));
```

Now if you `print_r($userList);`  it will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Doe
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Jane
            [last_name] => Doe
        )

)
```

Which your `foreach` statement should correctly iterate through.